# Ext JS simulate click in next cell of grid

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with two columns. One is a select and the other is a widget. When I select something in the select I would like for the widget in the next cell to be clicked(and open a popup). I have looked but don't get how to get around in the grid.

This is select column.

```
     {
            text: Visionera.util.MessageHelper.getMessage('ext.accountSettings.editCompanyCustomFields.customFieldType'),
            xtype: 'grid.column.combocolumn',
            dataIndex: 'customFieldTypeId',
            flex: 2,
            editable: true,
            store: Ext.create('Visionera.store.combo.IssueCustomFieldTypesStore'),
            editorSelectListener: function(combo, record, eOpts){                   
                var itemRecord = combo.up('editor').context.record;
                do something...
            }

        },
```

and this is the next column if it matters.

```
 {
            text: 'value',
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'typeAndValueList',
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            flex: 1,
            menuDisabled: true,
            widget: {
                xtype: 'flexiselectwidget',
                editable: true,
                selectorEmptyText: '',
                faIconForValue: 'fa-edit',
                contentXType: 'customfieldcontentpanel',
                listeners: {
                    select: 'onCustomFieldValueSelected',
                    scope: 'controller'
                }
            }
        },
```

There are some custom stuff in there but I hope this doesn't matter for this question. The `editorSelectListener` does get triggered.
And I just want this to create a clikc in the next cell.

Comment: We also had something like this requirement and need to set `minValue` of datefield in the editor. We achieved that by using `beforeedit` listener of `cellediting` plugin by this code: `var datefield = Ext.getCmp(context.cell.querySelector('div.x-form-field-date').id);
                        datefield.setMinValue(context.record.get('joiningDate') || new Date());`. Maybe this can give you any idea about your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Get the reference of the grid using combo.up('grid').
Then use the [down](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-down)() method to select the column. Then use the [fireEvent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#method-fireEvent) method to trigger the event programmatically and pass the required parameters.